# Number of ways of arrangement

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, backtracking

There are `N` students in the class and there are `N` seats.A student will sit only on his preferred seats.The problem is to find total valid arrangements possible.Example :There are `4` students and there are `4` seats and student a has pref seats numbered `[1,4]` and student b prefer seat no `[4]`.Likewise student c prefer `[2,3,4]` and student d prefer seat `[3]`.Now there is only one possible arrangement which is `dict[b]=4,dict[a]=1,dict[d]=3 and dict[c]=2`.Now this can be done using backtracking and greedy approach by allocating first students with seats that only have one choice and so on but for large `N` this approach would be expensive.Is there any other approach for such kind of problem?

I used Maximum Bipartite Matching to see whether the N students can be seated or not :

```
class graph:
    def __init__(self,graph):
        self.graph = graph 
        self.greedy = len(graph)    #greedy people
        self.seats = len(graph[0])  #total seats map

    def search(self, greed, match, flag):
        for i in range(self.seats):
            if self.graph[greed][i] and flag[i] == False:
                flag[i] = True
                if match[i] == -1 or self.search(match[i], match, flag):
                    match[i] = greed
                    return True
        return False


    def total(self):
        match = [-1] * self.seats
        result = 0 
        for i in range(self.greedy):
            flag = [False] * self.seats
            if self.search(i, match, flag):
                result += 1
        return result




egraph =[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]

var=graph(egraph)

print("yes" if var.total()==len(egraph) else "no")
```

Comment: `Finding all the perfect matchings in bipartite graphs`: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0893965994900450

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144423