# Solving a Maximum weight bipartite b-matching

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite, pulp

My question is regarding the Maximum Weight B-Matching problem.

**Bipartite matching** problems pair two sets of vertices in a bipartite graph. A **maximum weighted bipartite matching** (MWM) is defined as a matching where the sum of the values of the edges in the matching have a maximal value. A famous polynomial time algorithm for MWM is the Hungarian algorithm.

What I am interested in is a specific maximum weighted bipartite matching known as **weight bipartite B-matching problem**. A weight bipartite B-matching problem (WBM) seeks to match vertices so that each vertex is matched with no more vertices than its capacity `b` allows.

[image]

This figure (from [Chen et al.](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2983770)) shows the WBM problem. The input graph has score 2.2, the sum of all its edge weights. The blue edges of the solution H yield the highest score, 1.6, of all sub-graphs satisfying the red degree constraints.

Although there are a few recent works addressing the WBM problem ([this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7401047/) and [this](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2983770)), I cannot find any implementation of the algorithm. Does anybody know if the WBM problem already exists in any library like networkX?

Comment: Not sure if WBM has been implemented. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144423/all-possible-maximum-matchings-of-a-bipartite-graph)  question/answer should give you some ideas if you go the self-implementing route.

Comment: Thanks but unluckily that doesn't help. NetworkX has matching algorithms for bipartite graphs but for this particular case there is nothing.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the difference between MWM and WBM fully. Can you add a clarifying example, where the two solutions are different? Then maybe find a way to implement if with minimal extra work

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm solves the matching problem without considering the capacity of each vertex. The capacity `b` indicates how many edges can be connected to that vertex. We can say that MWM is a specific case of the WBM where the capacity of each vertex is 1. Modeling the problem using the capacity for the vertices helps us solving one-to-many problems, like 1 reviewer has the capacity of reviewing `b` articles.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to understand the problem: how is this different from the [knapsack problem (with multiple knapsacks)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)?

Comment: Nvm, I think it only becomes a canonical knapsack problem if the graph is fully connected.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Actually you model the problem in a different way which seems to be very interesting. The WBM problem has not been thought like that though. It is considered as a bipartite graph matching problem with constraints, conflicts and diversity. I'll do some experiments using your idea and write my findings here.

Comment: Yeah, there is a bunch of old-school discrete optimisation theory that could be elegantly expressed as graph problems but isn't. Doesn't mean they didn't figure out a thing or two. I am glad if the link gave you new ideas.

Comment: I have presented a solution for the weighted bipartite b-matching here: https://github.com/sinaahmadi/Bipartite_b_matching.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try and do this step by step, writing our own function to solve the WBM problem as specified in the question.

Using `pulp` it is not too difficult to formulate and solve a weighted bipartite matching (WBM), when we are given two sets of nodes (u and v, edge weights and vertex capacities.)

In Step 2 below, you'll find a (hopefully easy to follow) function to formulate WBM as an ILP and solve using `pulp.` Go through it to see if it helps. (You need to `pip install pulp`)

#### Step 1: Set up the bipartite graph capacities and edge weights

```
import networkx as nx
from pulp import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from_nodes = [1, 2, 3]
to_nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ucap = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2} #u node capacities
vcap = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1} #v node capacities

wts = {(1, 1): 0.5, (1, 3): 0.3,
       (2, 1): 0.4, (2, 4): 0.1,
       (3, 2): 0.7, (3, 4): 0.2}

#just a convenience function to generate a dict of dicts
def create_wt_doubledict(from_nodes, to_nodes):

    wt = {}
    for u in from_nodes:
        wt[u] = {}
        for v in to_nodes:
            wt[u][v] = 0

    for k,val in wts.items():
        u,v = k[0], k[1]
        wt[u][v] = val
    return(wt)
```

#### Step 2: Solve the WBM (formulated as an integer program)

Here's some description to make the code that follows easier to understand:

- The WBM is a variation of the Assignment problem.
- We 'match' nodes from the RHS to the LHS.
- The edges have weights
- The objective is to maximize the sum of the weights of the selected edges.
- Additional set of constraints: For each node, the number of selected edges has to be less than its 'capacity' which is specified.
- [PuLP Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) if you are not familiar with `puLP`

.

```
def solve_wbm(from_nodes, to_nodes, wt):
''' A wrapper function that uses pulp to formulate and solve a WBM'''

    prob = LpProblem("WBM Problem", LpMaximize)

    # Create The Decision variables
    choices = LpVariable.dicts("e",(from_nodes, to_nodes), 0, 1, LpInteger)

    # Add the objective function 
    prob += lpSum([wt[u][v] * choices[u][v] 
                   for u in from_nodes
                   for v in to_nodes]), "Total weights of selected edges"


    # Constraint set ensuring that the total from/to each node 
    # is less than its capacity
    for u in from_nodes:
        for v in to_nodes:
            prob += lpSum([choices[u][v] for v in to_nodes]) <= ucap[u], ""
            prob += lpSum([choices[u][v] for u in from_nodes]) <= vcap[v], ""


    # The problem data is written to an .lp file
    prob.writeLP("WBM.lp")

    # The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
    prob.solve()

    # The status of the solution is printed to the screen
    print( "Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
    return(prob)


def print_solution(prob):
    # Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
    for v in prob.variables():
        if v.varValue > 1e-3:
            print(f'{v.name} = {v.varValue}')
    print(f"Sum of wts of selected edges = {round(value(prob.objective), 4)}")


def get_selected_edges(prob):

    selected_from = [v.name.split("_")[1] for v in prob.variables() if v.value() > 1e-3]
    selected_to   = [v.name.split("_")[2] for v in prob.variables() if v.value() > 1e-3]

    selected_edges = []
    for su, sv in list(zip(selected_from, selected_to)):
        selected_edges.append((su, sv))
    return(selected_edges)
```

#### Step 3: Specify graph and call the WBM solver

```
wt = create_wt_doubledict(from_nodes, to_nodes)
p = solve_wbm(from_nodes, to_nodes, wt)
print_solution(p)
```

This gives:

```
Status: Optimal
e_1_3 = 1.0
e_2_1 = 1.0
e_3_2 = 1.0
e_3_4 = 1.0
Sum of wts of selected edges = 1.6
```

#### Step 4: Optionally, plot the graph using Networkx

```
selected_edges = get_selected_edges(p)


#Create a Networkx graph. Use colors from the WBM solution above (selected_edges)
graph = nx.Graph()
colors = []
for u in from_nodes:
    for v in to_nodes:
        edgecolor = 'blue' if (str(u), str(v)) in selected_edges else 'gray'
        if wt[u][v] > 0:
            graph.add_edge('u_'+ str(u), 'v_' + str(v))
            colors.append(edgecolor)


def get_bipartite_positions(graph):
    pos = {}
    for i, n in enumerate(graph.nodes()):
        x = 0 if 'u' in n else 1 #u:0, v:1
        pos[n] = (x,i)
    return(pos)

pos = get_bipartite_positions(graph)


nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos, with_labels=True, edge_color=colors,
       font_size=20, alpha=0.5, width=3)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show() 

print("done")
```

[image]

The blue edges are the ones that were selected for the WBM. Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: Ram, thank you very much for your detailed explications. Although your solution is really interesting, it seems to be ignoring the bipartite matching characteristic of the problem. The problem is not only optimizing the parameters, but to keep the graph bipartite while considering the capacity of each vertex. Otherwise, your solution could be a perfect one in the case that being bipartite is not important. Just to clarify, if we set the capacity of each vertex to 1, we should have a matched **bipartite** graph in the output which is not the case of your solution.

Comment: SIna, there is some subtle property of bipartite graphs (or bipartite matching) that I must be missing. Can you point out which property is violated and why in the example above? I will fix it.

Comment: Ram, set the capacity of the vertices to 1. Your solution should give a bipartite matched graph similar to the output of the Hungarian algorithm. Can you adopt your solution on the output of the Hungarian algorithm so that the optimization will be done with respect to the capacities?